# apache2 and php - please advise

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

OK, I originally posted this a question about php, but have since realized it could be a server configuration problem, which I know little about.  I left the php script in case, and am hoping someone might have some pointers on this - I already checked permissions (755).

`"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/register.php?name=uname&password=upassword"`

I was hoping someone here would be able to catch my error - sorry if this is obvious I've been learning as I go.

```
<?php

define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', 'password');



        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', USER, PASS);

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$upassword = password_hash($_POST['upassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES (?,?)';
$query->bind_param($uname, $upassword);



$queryResults = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $queryResults->execute();

    $queryResults = null; 
    $dbh = null; // close the connection
```

?>

This keeps giving me a 500 internal server error indicating the php script, (in firebug for firefox), and I can't really figure out where I'm going wrong.  I can also post ajax if needed.

Comment: just a side note: NEVER pass authentication data via $_GET. although $_POST can be sniffed, too, with a mitm-attack, $_GET will appear in every single logfile. also: NEVER EVER EVER store passwords as plaintext, please use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a Query String `http://localhost/register.php?name=uname&password=upassword"`. Its purely a GET Method.

Your have to check whether the GET Method is exist then you need to access the GET Method Data.

```
$uname = "";
if(isset($_GET['uname'])) {
    $uname = $_GET['uname'];
}

$upassword = "";
if(isset($_GET['password'])) {
    $upassword = $_GET['password'];
}

if(($uname != "") && ($upassword != "")) {
    $upassword = password_hash($upassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)", $uname, $upassword);

    ----- Statements ------
}
```

Comment: It can be any(POST/PUT/DELETE) http method, however `REQUEST_URI` always parsed into `$_GET` superglobal.

Comment: Thanks for the info - if I just replace all $_GET with $_POST and I will be using POST method right?  Is there anything I need to change to ensure POST not GET is used?

Comment: @user6559071 Nothing needed. If the answer is satisfied just mark this as Answer, by clicking the Tick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's throwing 500 error, but you clearly have error in code.

Your `$query` variable is string and it does not have `$query->bind_param()` method. I assume you are trying to do this (`bind_param` is MySqli while `bindParam` is PDO):

```
$dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam($uname, $upassword);
```

---

Also since you are passing variables via URL, than you must use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. Just make sure you first check if these parameters exists in `$_GET` and only than use them:

```
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $uname = $_GET['name'];
}
```

*NOTE* `?name=uname&password=upassword` means variable names are `name` and `password`. It's values are `$_GET['name'] = 'uname'` / `$_GET['password'] = 'upassword'`.

**Never pass username and password using $_GET as it's insecure. Better use some secure file to save them.**